# How do I rebuild an outlook profile in Microsoft Office Desktop Apps (Microsoft Store version)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016, windows-store-app, microsoft-store

I've got a corrupted Outlook profile, so it crashes on startup with an error "Cannot start Outlook. Cannot open the outlook window. The set of folders could not be opened". I want to rebuild the outlook profile, but this version of Office 2016 is from the Microsoft Store, meaning that my usual solutions to this problem are missing. For example, Control Panel>Mail does not exist, and the Outlook command-line switches like /safe and /profiles do not work. Is there any way I can rebuild an outlook profile without these tools?

Comment: Outlook has to be closed to rebuild the profile. So you cannot do this within Outlook. Try repairing or reinstalling Office to see if that repairs the Control Panel entry

Comment: The missing control panel entry is not a bug with Office. The Microsoft Store version of Office just does not have that entry in the control panel.

Comment: I see two products in the Store. Office 2016 subscription (what I own) and Microsoft 365 which I think is the same thing with a new name. You might try deleting the profile using the registry method. Be exceeding cautious of this.  https://smallbusiness.chron.com/delete-outlook-profile-registry-72556.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Control Panel>Mail does not exist when you’ve installed Office or Outlook via the Windows Store.

However, you can still access your Profile management interface via Start-> typeoutlook.exe /manageprofiles

For your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/96cca680-9b38-455e-8edc-404dcde992e9/mail-icon-missing-from-control-panel?forum=outlook

Hope this can be helpful.